# What is the maximum gold find that can be obtained from each type of follower?

Tags: diablo-iii

Gold find, magic find and bonus experience for the follower adds a 20% to your total. From rings and an amulet the follower can get 100% more gold find, so you get 20% more gold find.

What is the maximum gold find that can be obtained from each type of follower?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best you can achieve is 150% (30% for you) with Eirena (the enchantress) :

- 50% on a rare amulet
- 50% on rare rings(2x)
- 50% on [The Grand Vizier](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/item/the-grand-vizier)

The other possibilities is 135% (27% for you) for Kormac (the templar) :

- 50% on a rare amulet
- 50% on rare rings(2x)
- 25% on the shield
- 10% with the Wirt's original Leg

The scoundrel can't achieve much (only amulet and rings) since I don't remember any crossbow or bow giving gold find